# Embed form in email in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to collect feedback through emails. For this I am thinking of embedding a feedback form in the email itself that the user can fill and submit. Upon submitting, the form will post data to my application where I can process the data.

Please suggest how this can be done or is there any other way I can achieve this.

Note: I also thought about embedding google form in my app but I can't figure out how this can be done. 
Also, my application is private, so, it can't be exposed to public.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it -- write an html form in the body of your email, configured to post to a route of your rails app. Depending on your audience it may not be a good idea. [Many email clients don't display inline forms correctly](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/will-it-work/forms/), and it's hard to do client side validation. Linking to a Google Form is a better idea if you can't make a Rails form public.

Answer (score 0):

Most HTML email clients will not show the input elements to forms (think of how much spam you'd get).

There is a [great resource here](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/will-it-work/forms/):

> The short of it is that email clients consider email forms to be a
>   **security risk**. While some email clients simply warn you of potential
>   danger, others outright disable the forms. So if your client wants to
>   send out a form, they should know that most of their recipients will
>   never be able to use it. And for those who can, they’ll think twice
>   about submitting data when they see a warning from their email client.

--

In my experience, email should only be used as a form of light communication; less text the better. Pictures work really well.

---

> I want to collect feedback through emails

A much better solution will be to send a series of links (as answers to specific questions) in the email body. This will allow you to send the user to the "feedback" page, from where you'd collect their data.

Even better - you could encode the link to pass their `name` & `email` which you could then populate on the page itself...

```
#email
<a href="yoururl.com/feedback/new?name=your+name&email=email@email.com">Fill out the form</a>

#app/views/feedback/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @feedback do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Name", curent_user.name || params[:name] %>
   <%= f.email_field :email, placeholder: "Email", current_user.email || params[:email] %>
<% end %>
```

You could back it up with the following controller and routes:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :feedback

#app/controllers/feedback_controller.rb
class FeedbackController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @feedback = Feedback.new
   end
   def create
      @feedback = Feedback.new feedback_params
      @feedback.save
   end

   private

   def feedback_params
      params.require(:feedback).permit(:x, :y, :z)
   end
end
```

This will allow you to send people to a `new` feedback form page.

--

If you wanted to have a more "interactive" feel to the email, you could make a series of links (in the email body itself), which would send the user to the new `feedback` view as well:

```
#email
<h3>Question 3</h3>
<a href="yoururl.com/feedback/new?name=richard&email=peck@email.com&3=a">a</a>
<a href="yoururl.com/feedback/new?name=richard&email=peck@email.com&3=b">b</a>
<a href="yoururl.com/feedback/new?name=richard&email=peck@email.com&3=c">c</a>
<a href="yoururl.com/feedback/new?name=richard&email=peck@email.com&3=d">d</a>
```

This will give the illusion of interactivity, although not interactivity itself.